# Can I expect any problems (sagging?) if I build my fence with 6'x8' panels like this?

Tags: fence, horizontal

the horizontal boards will be 1x6x8
the posts will be 4x4x6

I am not sure if I should install the top boards or not
[image]

[image]

Update: The top board is not a concern. Sagging for the horizontal boards is my concern. Do I need the middle vertical 2x4 ?

Update: here is the final result. No cap board I will only cap the post. The picture shows the middle vertical reinforcement uncut yet and so are the posts.
That reinformcement is needed not for sagging but to prevent the boards to bend in the horizontal direction
[image]

Comment: What makes you think that leaving off the top boards will compromise structural integrity.

Comment: nothing -I just mentioned that as a FYI>
those boards are more to protect the fence and for aesthetical reasons

Comment: OK, then what is the question or perceived issues with this design?

Comment: I was hoping someone would tell me that the vertical 2x4x6 in the middle is not needed. I updated the question

Comment: The 2x4 stiffeners would make the fence much stronger. Without them the fence might look good at first, but lose its shape over time. A kid climbing on a fence like this would be more likely to cause damage the fence if there were no stiffeners.

Comment: Vertical rail fences are commonly capped for aesthetics and security, not for structural integrity. It is harder to scale a capped fence. (Try pulling yourself up by gripping a flat 90 deg board vs the thin end of a 1x6.) The security consideration goes away with a horizontal rail fence. That design is an invitation to climbers. Capping it would just provide a comfortable perch on top.

Comment: I think a cap is a total wast and it provides a home for paper wasps . a short fence it would help the looks but this looks like a 6' tall fence at 6"5" I could see the opening but being open at the top would reduce the chance of paper wasps and bald face hornets.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As shown in the update the top boards are not needed but the vertical reinforcement in the middle is needed
The post masters are steel set in concrete (see my other posts around here about this design) 
The only issue I have is that the boards dried up and I ended up with spaces between them. Not very big but they are there. I wish I had the idea to let them dry up first or I wish I had the money to make this out of cedar

Answer (score 0):

I have seen one cedar fence installation in a very shady yard in Dallas where the cap board has kept the top fence rail from drying out. This is a 1st rate cedar fence in which the top rail is rotting from staying wet. The cap board is very attractive, but if this is the result it should be rethought.

Comment: I udpdated the question, the cap board is not necessary a concern

Answer (score 0):

The vertical 2x4s will support the horizontal slats, but it is hard to say whether they are necessary. The use of these intermediate supports might be "heavy-duty-itis", but if that is what your fence installer uses, then it might be a good idea. Without this intermediate support over time the horizontal boards might bow and the fence lose its neat appearance.

Edit: Six-ft fences with vertical slats have *three* rails and taller fences may have four rails. This suggests that the fences with horizontal boards should have the 2x4s between the posts to support and stiffen the board slats.

Comment: should I rest that stiffener on the ground? (worried about rotting)

Comment: @MiniMe, the 2x4 are probably either southern pine peasure treated for outdoor exposure or cedar. As with the horizontal slats they are OK to get rained on but not rated for ground contact. As a practical matter, this typically means that fence boards and rails are installed close to but not flush with the ground. It's common for the installer to slide one of the 1x6 rails underneath to create a 3/4" gap to the ground. This means the bottom rail will get wet from rain and ground vegetation but will not sit in damp soil. The same consideration applies to the 2x4s.

Comment: For the stiffener 2x4s be careful to use dimensionally stable wood, such as cedar. Pressure treated pine can warp. First quality pressure treated Douglas Fir *may* be dimensionally stable, but PT pine is not. Redwood would also be good but of course is more expensive and there would be no point in using it unless the boards were also redwood. I also agree that the 2x4 stiffeners should not reach the ground. There would be no benefit and it might look strange. Where is this fence--state and city?